# How to ensure code is always called before page unload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, websocket, onbeforeunload

Usually this isn't important, and it may not even be too important for my situation, but I'd like to know if there is a reasonable way to implement this.

My page automatically opens a web socket connection. In order to be a better client I want the client to clean up after itself and close the websocket before the page gets unloaded.

My hope is that the browser would have the foresight to call `close()` for me when the page is unloaded, but in case it doesn't, how can I leverage the `onbeforeunload` message (or some such) to do some "final cleanup" (not unlike `atexit()` in C)?

Suppose I have some system where I want my clients to send an "exiting" message to my websocket server for some reason.

I can do this now:

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function () {
    websocket.close(); // websocket is a WebSocket
});
```

But suppose `close()` is actually an asynchronous call (is it?) and I want to **make sure** the socket.onclose callback fires prior to actually unloading the page! Can this be done?

Comment: If you control the server, you can require a client-side heartbeat every n minutes - if the heartbeat is not received by the server, then the server closes the socket to clean up any orphaned client socket the browser may have left hanging around.

Comment: @jfriend00 That sounds like a perfectly good approach to deal with this. It also appears that my `close()` inside the `onbeforeunload` is doing the trick.

Comment: I think you can't count on a `close()` working in all browsers, but there is no harm in trying it there.  The heartbeat covers all cases, even including browser bugs in notifying you of the window close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no sure fire way of making sure an asynchronous call is fully executed in modern browsers. Older versions could be held up with a while loop, but current browsers will kill any process and continue. Reason is they want the user experience to be fast, you holding them up does them harm.

Comment: Yeah doing a busy loop to hold up the unload wouldn't be a proper solution.

Comment: @StevenLu it used to be the only solution. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
window.onunload=function(){
//your code here
}
```

i guess we do have this.

Comment: This should be sufficient for non-async stuff but to verify my `websocket.onclose` has run (which is async) it's not sufficient. Perhaps there is no solution.